# Improving number guessing game code

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I'm trying to make a small guessing game where it generates a random number, and the user enters in a number using a `TextBox` and `Button`. Currently it is creating the random number and doing everything I want, but every time the user presses submit on the button, it generates a new random number for them to guess

I am very new to ASP.NET type stuff, so my code is probably inefficient and incorrect lol, so I have two particular questions.

1. How can I improve my code to make it work better/work at all.
2. Do I need a runner class to make it work, and how would I do so?

```
public partial class WebPageSeparated : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int randNum;
    private int theirGuess;
    public WebPageSeparated()
    {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        randNum = randomNum.Next(0, 10);
        theirGuess = 0;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Guessing game! Guess a number between [0,10) to see if you can get it right!";
        new WebPageSeparated();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            theirGuess = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            if (theirGuess != this.randNum)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Sorry, wrong number.  Please try again!";
            }
            else if(theirGuess == this.randNum)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Correct! A new number has been generated, go ahead and try to do it again!";
                new WebPageSeparated();
            }
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Enter a number [1,10)";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So when they hit submit it doesn't return one of those two responses?

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski it does, but the number that is supposed to be guessed changes every time you submit a new number

Comment: Step 1: Do not use exceptions to control program flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things are wrong with your code:

You should never create a new instance of your page (`new WebPageSeparated()`). A new instance is created every time you navigate to the page (by entering its URL in the browser) and whenever you cause a PostBack (e.g. by clicking an `asp:button`).

If you want to have some code, which runs only the first time the page is invoked (i.e. not during a PostBack, only when navigating to the page), then you should wrap that code in a `if (!IsPostBack) {}` block.

Because a new instance of the page is created for each PostBack, you cannot store any state (the random number) in an instance-field of the page. You have to find another place where you store the state, e.g:

- in a static field, e.g: `private static int randNum`

  - note: this is not recommended, since the static field is shared between all instances of your page (doesn't work if multiple users are on your website at the same time)
- in a session variable, e.g. `Session["randNum"] = randomNum.Next(0, 10)`
- in the `ViewState` of the page, e.g. `ViewState["randNum"] = ...`

  - this is what I'd recommend for your sample
- in a database

---

With all these points in mind, your `Page_Load` method would look something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Random randomNum = new Random();
            randNum = randomNum.Next(0, 10);
            ViewState["randNum"] = randNum;
        }
        else
        {
            randNum = (int) ViewState["randNum"];
        }
        Label1.Text = "Guessing game! Guess a number between [0,10) to see if you can get it right!";
    }
```

Also, in the case, the user guesses the correct number, you should generate and store a new random number (as done inside the `if (!IsPostBack)`).

---

Finally, some topics you might want to read more about: Page Lifecycle, PostBack, Viewstate, Session-state

Answer (score -2):

The reason is asp.net **postback** all the data to server for every action performed in the browser. Since you are generating a random number in the **constructor** your facing this issue. I guesss this will help you.

```
public partial class WebPageSeparated : System.Web.UI.Page

{

private int randNum;
private int theirGuess;




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    randNum = randomNum.Next(0, 10);
    theirGuess = 0;
    Label1.Text = "Guessing game! Guess a number between [0,10) to see if you can get it right!";
    new WebPageSeparated();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       try
        {
            theirGuess = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            if (theirGuess != this.randNum)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Sorry, wrong number.  Please try again!";
            }
            else if(theirGuess == this.randNum)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Correct! A new number has been generated, go ahead and try to do it again!";
                new WebPageSeparated();
            }
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Enter a number [1,10)";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code that you have above and it didnt fix it, i made it so when it says "try again" it prints out what the random number is and every time I press submit on the button the number changes..

Comment: I just now noticed that the new WebPageSeparated() instantiation is done inside the event handlers which is not necessary. But I wonder why you are instantiating every time.